# MongoDb: db.getUser() in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm currently writing an app in PHP that connects to a MongoDB database.

I've managed to successfully authenticate a user with the dbAdmin role in the MongoDB Database that I've setup, and I've created a user "TestUser" with no roles that I want to get information about while authenticated as the dbAdmin User. however I can't figure out how to run the "db.getUser()" command from PHP.

My understanding is that I should be able to use the "MongoDB::command()" method to run any actual mongoDB commands directly, however, the following code...

```
$mongo = new MongoClient("localhost:27017");
$mongoDb = $mongo->{'test'}
$mongoDb->authenticate($username, $password); //This returns a successful response of array('ok' => 1)
print_r($mongoDb->command(array("getUser" => "TestUser")));
```

Generates this response: -

```
(
    [ok] => 0
    [errmsg] => no such command: getUser
    [code] => 59
    [bad cmd] => stdClass Object
        (
            [getUser] => TestUser
        )
)
```

The "getUser" is a command of a Database in MongoDB though, right? If so, why am I getting this response, and how do I construct a correct statement to be able to get information about a User from MongoDB in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this more, by fetching a list of all possible methods available to the database by using...

```
$mongoDb->command(array("listCommands" => 1));
```

This informed me that "getUser" apparently is not an existing command. I'm not sure why not, I guess it's because it's a User Management command and not a typical Database Command.

At any rate, "usersInfo" is a command that is available. By doing the following...

```
$mongoDb->command(array("usersInfo" => array("user" => $username, "db" => $database)));
```

I was able to get the data about the user that I wanted, so I guess that answers my question. Hopefully this helps anyone else whose encountering the same problem trying to setup their PHP app with MongoDb.