# Unable to get collection user as a JSON object (getuser())

Tags: node.js, mongodb

getUser() doesnt exist in MongoDB Node.js Native Driver .

See this :
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/

or

[db.getUser in node.js mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884035/db-getuser-in-node-js-mongodb)

I'm using mongoDb shell v4.0.10 .
And this is a part of my package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
"bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-mongo-db": "^2.0.4",
"express-session": "^1.16.2",
"express-sessions": "^1.0.6",
"mongodb": "^3.2.7",
"multer": "^1.4.1",
"sharp": "^0.22.1"
```

}

I can't get any user data , following my successfull log in that is working well (with the "jose" user) .

```
app.post('/getAuth', function(req, res) {
            var user = req.body;
            MongoClient.connect("mongodb://" + user.username + ":" + user.password + "@localhost:27017/myDb", function(err, client) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.status(403).send({
                            errorCode: "403"
                        });
                    } else {
                        db = client.db('myDb');
                        var name = "jose";
                        var collection = db.collection('users');
                        collection.findOne({
                                user: name
                            }, function(err, doc) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                if (doc) console.log("Found: " + name + ");
                                    else console.log("Not found: " + name);
                                });
                        }
                    });
            })
```

node.js says :

```
Not found: jose
```

While, the user jose exists in the Users list of the collection;

I've also tried "Users" instead of "users" as a collection name, with no luck.

Using Mongo3t, it shows that "Users" doesnt seem to be a collection, but a dedicated environnement named Users, how can I access this from node.js ?.

[image]

**Edit 2** : This is a code i've found on stack overflow, but it says NULL :

```
   var cmd = { getUser: "jose", db: "myDb"};
            db.command(cmd, function (err, r) {
            console.log(r);
         });
```

This is the error :

```
{ MongoError: no such command: 'getUser'
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\UwAmp\www\evaluetoncoinnode\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:443:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at processMessage (C:\UwAmp\www\evaluetoncoinnode\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:364:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\UwAmp\www\evaluetoncoinnode\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:533:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'no such command: \'getUser\'',
  code: 59,
  codeName: 'CommandNotFound',
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

**Edit 3** : to explain better, this is what i need to query : Any user and his customData :

[image]

--------------------**SOLVED**-----------------

Thanks to this post : 
[MongoDb: db.getUser() in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676684/mongodb-db-getuser-in-php)

I can get my user data with this code now (please notice, usersInfo() exists , but getUser() doesnt exist. :

```
app.post('/getAuth', function(req, res) {
    var user = req.body;
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://" + user.username + ":" + user.password + "@localhost:27017/myDb", function(err, client) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(403).send({
                    errorCode: "403"
                });
            } else {

                db = client.db('myDb');

                var cmd = { usersInfo: "jose"};

                db.command(cmd, function (err, user) {
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log(user); // WORKING
                 });
    })
```

Console.log Result :

```
{ users:
   [ { _id: 'myDb.jose',
       userId: [Binary],
       user: 'jose',
       db: 'myDb',
       roles: [Array],
       mechanisms: [Array] } ],
  ok: 1 }
```

Comment: You are doing the request to a mongodb Collection while you want to find a Database User.

Comment: I agree, but how should I do , cause getUser() doesnt exist ?

Comment: You have to use an admin instance. Take a look at this documentation: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Admin.html  
I've never used that so I can't really help you on that point... but there's a part of the documentation which speaks of db users. There are various example on that page, you may find what you want ;)

Comment: Thank you but the jose User has the dbAdmin role on this dB, it should work, plus jose can already fire the function  db.addUser() with success and add new profiles

Comment: Did you try to execute the same request in you viewer ? (I guess it is Robomongo or robo3t)

Comment: db.getUser("jose") is working in robot3t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--------------------**SOLVED**-----------------

Thanks to this post : 
[MongoDb: db.getUser() in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676684/mongodb-db-getuser-in-php)

I can get my user data with this code now (please notice, usersInfo() exists , but getUser() doesnt exist. :

```
app.post('/getAuth', function(req, res) {
    var user = req.body;
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://" + user.username + ":" + user.password + "@localhost:27017/myDb", function(err, client) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(403).send({
                    errorCode: "403"
                });
            } else {

                db = client.db('myDb');

                var cmd = { usersInfo: "jose"};

                db.command(cmd, function (err, user) {
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log(user); // WORKING
                 });
    })
```

Console.log Result :

```
{ users:
   [ { _id: 'myDb.jose',
       userId: [Binary],
       user: 'jose',
       db: 'myDb',
       roles: [Array],
       mechanisms: [Array] } ],
  ok: 1 }
```